# Displaying Data Using a Custom Select Query in Wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I want to show data from a non-wordpress website in a Wordpress page both on the same server. I have the below code but it doesn't display. Guess I'm missing out something.

```
$my_db = new wpdb('username', 'password', 'database', 'localhost');
$query = "SELECT name FROM contributors LIMIT 10";
$result = $my_db->get_results($query);
echo $result['name'];
```

Comment: `var_dump($result); exit;` What do you see?

Comment: shows an unformatted result of the data.

Comment: Can you `var_dump(json_encode($result, true)); exit;` and paste that? or a sample of it if it's a large result?

Comment: this is what came out 
string(188) "[{"name":"Kunal "},{"name":"Amit"},{"name":"Stock Contributor"},{"name":"amit"},{"name":"anil"},{"name":"oloyedeola"},{"name":"Rohit"},{"name":"mahajan"},{"name":"Mahajan"},{"name":"Eni"}]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `json_decode`.

$result is an object. So do this:

```
$my_db = new wpdb('username', 'password', 'database', 'localhost');
$query = "SELECT name FROM contributors LIMIT 10";
$result = $my_db->get_results($query);

foreach($result as $data) {
    echo $data->name;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As I suspected, you have an array. So all you need to do is loop through it!

```
<?php

$result = json_decode('[{"name":"Kunal "},{"name":"Amit"},{"name":"Stock Contributor"},{"name":"amit"},{"name":"anil"},{"name":"oloyedeola"},{"name":"Rohit"},{"name":"mahajan"},{"name":"Mahajan"},{"name":"Eni"}]', true);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}

/*
Kunal 
Amit 
Stock 
Contributor 
amit 
anil 
oloyedeola 
Rohit 
mahajan 
Mahajan 
Eni
*/
```

Comment: entering it this way works, thanks. But I need to generate the names dynamically but creating the recordset isn't working.

Comment: ignore my fake `$result`, that's just for demo purposes and obviously you will use the db `$result`. Just try the loop part!

Comment: something doesn't seem to be working with mine. I don't know.
'''
$query = "SELECT name FROM contributors LIMIT 10";
$set = $my_db->get_results($query);
$result = json_decode($set, true); 


foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
'''